# Optimize mysql query performance with order by

Tags: mysql, spatial

I'm trying to optimize the following mysql query:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'fr_FR';
SET @j = '{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[1.31321,48.024146],[1.63456,48.024146],[1.63456,48.150283],[1.31321,48.150283],[1.31321,48.024146]]]}}';
SET @zone = ST_GeomFromGeoJson(@j);
create temporary table A as select id, field1, field2, ... from mybase WHERE val > 0 and ST_CONTAINS(@zone, pt) and year(date_date) IN ('2022','2021','2020') order by date_date DESC limit 200;
select * from A WHERE 1;
...
```

Currently the creation of the temporary table takes 15s but when I remove the order by date_date DESC, it is down to 0.1s !

Current indexes: spatial on 'pt' field and index on 'date_date' field

EXPLAIN shows that only date index is used and not spatial when I keep "order by" statement. If I remove "order by date_date, it uses the spatial index.

The table has 8 million lines.

Any idea on how to optimize the order by ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

*Probably* the Optimizer will use the `SPATIAL` index first.  You do have such??

The problem is you have 3 clauses in the `WHERE`, each of which *might* be able to make use of an index.  But not two of them can use the same index.

If it turns out to beneficial to use an index on `date_date`, then change

```
      and  year(date_date) IN ('2022','2021','2020')
```

to

```
      AND date_date >= '2020-01-01'
      AND date_date  < '2022-01-01'
```

and have

```
  INDEX(date_date)
```

*If* the optimizer chose to use that index, that reformulation would let it avoid sorting the results, and *might* avoid reading more than 200 rows.

I can't be more certain because it depends on the distribution of the data and the phase of the moon.